# Angular change detection only triggering once on consecutive Ngrx-store updates

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

In the following scenario, Angular change detection is not triggering in the way I would expect it to. I am using ngrx-store to hold my application state.

1. Initially, I have state S1.
2. I trigger an action A1. A reducer listening for A1 updates the state to S2. An effect triggers action A2.
3. A reducer listening for A2 updates the state back to S1.

In the above situation, there are two state updates (S1 -> S2 -> S1). However, at the end of this series of actions, my components OnChange is only triggering once (S1 -> S1). I am using a standard Observable with async pipe and child component with @Input.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent-component',
    template: `<app-time-entry [timeEntry]="timeEntry$ | async"></app-time-entry>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
    timeEntry$: Observable<TimeEntryRow>;

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
        this.timeEntry$ = this.store.select(state => state.time.timeEntry);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-time-entry',
    template: `{{timeEntry.hours}}`
})
export class TimeEntryComponent {
    @Input() timeEntry: TimeEntry;
}
```

Why is the change detection only happening once in this case? I have verified that my state is properly updating between each action, so why are the bindings only updated once? I would expect the async pipe to pass along the changed state twice, thus triggering the child components OnChange twice as well.

## Update

As suggested by Kevin below, adding a delay into the effect causes both OnChanges to trigger as expected. This would suggest that the Angular "tick" is happening after both state updates have finished.

Comment: Have you verified in `TimeEntryComponent` that `OnChanges` is only called once?

Comment: Yes, I'm logging in the OnChanges event. It is triggered once and the changes variable shows the current and previous values are both S1, where I would expect the previous value to be S2 if it were triggered during the first state update as well.

Comment: The reason for this is that your `store.dispatch(A1)` call ends up doing a lot of stuff. It dispatches the A1 action, which changes state, then is picked up by an effect, that then dispatches A2, which modifies the state. This is all done during that one dispatch of action 1. Angular can't run change detection in the middle of that, so you get one OnChanges. That's why adding the delay works - the dispatching of A2 is no longer done during the dispatch of A1, so you see two OnChanges because angular had the chance to run change detection between the two dispatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be normal. Your state changed twice during the same 'tick' (ie: you dispatching action A1 changed the state twice, one directly from the reducer handling your action, and the second time from the effect dispatching the second action).

But change detection is run once. So you only see the last change. I imagine if your effect was dispatching the action a latter time (maybe by using the delay operator) you would see OnChanges being called twice. I'm surprise you see the S2->S1 change though instead of S1->S1 (they have the same content, but are different objects since state is immutable), so it might not be what's happening.

Hard to see if this is what's happening without seeing all the code. What does your effect look like? Is it dispatching an action immediately, or is it doing some kind of AJAX request, and dispatching the action when it gets the result?

Comment: The effect dispatches the action almost immediately. It looks at the state, checks if certain values are valid, and then calls the second action.

Comment: Sorry, I am seeing S1->S1 (same content, different objects). By S2->S1 I just meant this is the action where I'm seeing the OnChange called. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: You are also correct that if I put a delay in my effect, I do see OnChanges trigger twice. I don't consider this to be a solution though... Is there someway I can force change detection to happen in this situation?

Comment: Try adding the delay operator and test my theory. I'm pretty sure that's what's happening. If you don't quite understand what's going on, I can explain further. Also you might want to look at [this article](https://medium.com/@m3po22/stop-using-ngrx-effects-for-that-a6ccfe186399) to make sure you really do need an effect. I agree with #1 and #2, but I think #3 is debatable.

Comment: Without knowing more about what you are trying to do and why getting two distinct changes is important, I can't really give a solution, sorry. With the limited information I have, it seems like you shouldn't use an effect and a second action. Just do everything in your reducer handling the first action?